# What is the "Eco1.User" layer in KiCad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, pcb-layers

In KiCad (Pcbnew), and perhaps other PCB layout programs, there is an *Eco1.User* layer and also an *Eco2.User* layer.

What does the "Eco" stand for? And what are these drawing layers typically used for, in particular, do they have an "official" purpose?

Google doesn't turn up much on the topic, although I found alternate spellings **ECO1** and **E.C.O. 1**.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For recording "Engineering Change Order" documentation, comments, artwork changes, etc. (Similar to a list of revisions with graphic capabilities.)